# How to set up ngrx in Angular 4 app?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have an Angular 4 app.

How to inject the Store into every component and how to handle reducers in different files while keeping the project's structure?

I saw [ngrx/example-app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app), but since my app will have really many components, that structuring doesn't fit my needs and I can't figure out how to weave ngrx into my app.

Project structure is as below:

- app

  - features

    - user

      - profile

        - profile.actions.ts
        - profile.reducer.ts
        - profile.service.ts
        - profile.component.ts
        - profile.component.html
        - profile.component.less
      - user.module.ts
      - user.routing.module.ts
    - market

      - ... *(similar to user)*
    - admin

      - ... *(similar to user)*
  - app.component.ts
  - app.module.ts
  - app.routing.module.ts
  - app.store.ts
  - main.reducer.ts

Is it possible to use ngrx as we do it with angular routing? I mean, we can separate routing into main and child modules across the app  and then import them in a specific module of the app with `RouterModule.forChild(userRoutes)` method.

Comment: You might want to give a look to an ngrx starter I've made: https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter I tried to explain a lot of things in readme + code comments